# iOS In App Purchase capabilities says: "An App ID with Identifier 'com.example.App' is not available"

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, ios-provisioning

I have created an iOS App ID in iOS Dev Center under Certificates, Identities, and Profiles and enabled it for In-App-Purchases. Let's say its name is `App` and the id is `com.example.app`.

If I view the corresponding app's In-App Purchase capabilities in Xcode 5.0.2 the tool indicates an error and offers to "Add the In App Purchase entitlement to Your App ID" in the form of a "Fix Issue" button. If I press the button I receive this error message:

> An App ID with Identifier 'com.example.App' is not available. Please
>   enter a different string.

How can I overcome this problem? The identifier `com.example.App` seems to be derived from the targets bundle identifier, whose suffix seems in turn derived from the project name. Those should not change.

And why does Xcode not pick up the existing App ID that I've already created in iOS Dev center. It spells app in lower case, but I [understand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7688379/does-bundle-id-need-to-be-case-sensitive) that shouldn't matter, and in any case it does not seem to be possible to replace it with an upper-case version because this would require deletion of an app id first, which [seems impossible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/996477/removing-app-id-from-developer-connection).

So how can I fix the issue in Xcode (e.g. by directly editing capabilities) and what is the recommended workflow between Xcode and iOS Dev Center for adding capabilities in the first place?

Comment: Just specify proper identifier in plist with out appending project name on that, and make sure you are logged in from correct account

Comment: @DineshKaushik +1 I've changed `Bundle identifier` from `com.example.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}` (the default) to `com.example.app` in `App-Info.plist` and that apparently fixed the problem by enforcing the lower-case version. If you want to turn your comment into an answer, I'd be happy to accept it. Thx in any case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just specify proper identifier in plist with out appending project name on that,

and make sure you are logged in from correct account.

Comment: Could you provide a bit more information? What is "proper"?