# No suitable records were found verify your bundle identifier is correct

Tags: ios, xcode6, app-store-connect

I have created an app in App Store Connect and it has been in the "prepare for submission" state for more than 3 days. When I try to archive my app, and submit it to the app store it, displays this message:

> No suitable application records were found. Verify your bundle identifier is correct.

Comment: Is your app in `iTunesConnect` has selected same identifier for which you are `archive` application?

Comment: yes I have selected same id

Comment: Did you sign in to xcode with the same Apple Id as itunesconnect?

Comment: Yes I have signed in using that id only

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22278823/xcode-5-no-application-records-were-found-when-trying-to-validate-an-archive

Comment: I believe you can found the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22278823/xcode-5-no-application-records-were-found-when-trying-to-validate-an-archive from @Bamsworld.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Just found the Error. I used one capital letter in bundle id. but I have used small letters in Xcode's bundle id. now I changed that as like in the app id. and now I successfully uploaded my app to Appstore Connect.

Comment: In my case I had forgotten to Create the app with the respecitve App Bundle ID in the iTunesConnect

Comment: If they would just show each of the non-matching values it would be easy to correct.

Comment: @Sasho you are god !

Comment: In my case, I was using 2 developer accounts in Xcode. I removed unwanted one & I was able to resolve issue.

Comment: My case was I had not created the app on appstoreconnect, had only registered profiles and Id's. On creating the app, upload worked! Thanks @Sasho

Answer (score 62):

generally this happens when you have not created your app from apple developer account->iTunes Connect->Click on My App->click on plus sign (+)->New App->And fill up the whole info and Choose Your Bundle Id for the app you are uploading now.

Comment: This was it for me.  I didn't create my app in the App Store Connect.

Comment: Thanks mate. You made my day.

Comment: how do you choose the bundle id, if the bundle id doesn't get populate with the recent one even though App ID was created in the developer's page?

Comment: @Marin I had to wait about 5 mins for the newly created bundle ID to show up in the dropdown menu

Comment: This solved mine.  I totally missed out on creating an app in the ituneconnect.  Thank you @Avi

Answer (score 50):

Just check that app you configured on iTuneconnect is having same bundle identifier that you are using to upload app.

URL: https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/apps

Comment: And same app name (uppercase/lowercase)

Answer (score 32):

**iTunes Connect || App Store Connect** (website):

In your browser, go to [iTunes connect/ App Store Connect](https://appstoreconnect.apple.com).

1. Add your New App / edit your existing app.
2. Go to App information.
3. Check the Bundle ID name.
4. If there is no bundle ID, make sure you create one.
5. I used the WildCard bundle ID. That means, your complete bundle ID is likely to be com.organizationName.* and the suffix (exampleApp).
   Xcode:
6. Go to your Workspace / Project.
7. Go to your project.
8. Select the General Tab.

Ensure the Bundle Identifier is the name you set in iTunes Connect.

For example: **com.orgnanizationName.appName**

It seems you have to start the App Store submission process in iTunesConnect.

[image: App Store Connect Icon]
[image: Add App]

Comment: Yes that was m case. this error is shown you have not added the app in https://appstoreconnect.apple.com.

Comment: This was me as well.  I created the APP ID on the 'portal' but then forgot to create an App Store Connect app that USED that APP ID signature I created on the Apple App Portal.

Comment: Thank you,  I spent a lots of time with the error, check my id over and over, and the problem is just I have to create a new app on App connect  first... what a joke...

Comment: Thx for the support :)

Answer (score 25):

What did the fix for me is to allow app access to all users:

1. Go to AppStore Connect
2. Go to My App
3. Under Additional Information, click on 'Edit User Access'
4. Select 'Full Access'
5. This allowed me to upload the app the first time (via Xcode & Application Loader)

After the initial upload, i can switch back to 'Limited Access' and upload just fine.

Comment: Tried different solutions but this one worked for me

Comment: When bundle ids are the same and you can not find any mistake. This is the answer. Change your Limited Access to Full Access.

Comment: This is exactly what I need! Should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 13):

I believe you can found the answer here [Xcode 5 - "No application records were found" when trying to Validate an Archive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22278823/xcode-5-no-application-records-were-found-when-trying-to-validate-an-archive) from @Bamsworld.

As you already mentioned and as per the documentation - [App Distribution Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/SubmittingYourApp/SubmittingYourApp.html)

Important: You can’t validate your app unless the app record in iTunes Connect is in the “Waiting for Upload” or later state
After you add a new app in iTunes connect there will be an amber light along with its status. It will most likely read "Prepare For Upload". To get it to the "Waiting For Upload" state click view details for the app and in the top right there should be a blue button that says "Ready to Upload Binary". Click this and follow the given directions.

Comment: In my case the problem was the Mac running out of space. Application Loader instead of giving an error about disk space gives random error like this a several others (you can give the same *.ipa and it will return random real errors but indeed you are just out of space)

Answer (score 12):

If you use Application Loader, then check if you are logged to the correct account. It was my case and it can happen if you manage account for various clients.

[image]

Comment: Thnaks a lot buddy.. The same was with me

Answer (score 9):

In my case, I had 2 Apple IDs in my Xcode preferences (Xcode -> Preferences -> Accounts), so I had to remove one. After I removed Apple ID that I didn't need, validation process worked just fine.

Wasted a few hours, just because the error message is useless. This is so frustrating.

[image: 1]

Comment: Same goes here, I had 2 accounts, one is the developer and the other one is the owner, and the developer one listed first. So probably Xcode tried to act on behalf of the developer user

Comment: Same problem, it solved my probrem,  it wasted my time

Answer (score 6):

Double check the `Bundle OS Type code` in your App's `info.plist`, for me, the only way around this error was to set it to `APPL`.

The weird thing is that the error was regarding to my frameworks bundle id, tho changing the above in my app solved it.

Comment: I've tried everything else and this was the solution that ended up solving this for me! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 5):

Using Application Loader worked in my case.

[image]

Comment: Could you please add more details?

Comment: In XCode menu bar, select Xcode -> Open Developer Tool -> Application Loader -> select your *.ipa file (you can export from archived versions in Organizer windows) and upload.

Answer (score 3):

Chek your app ID in the Apple Developer Center. Then, use exactly the same name in Bundler Identifier.

Answer (score 3):

I have to manually sign the app. Created new certificate and new profile. Set code signing to Manual. Only then i was able to upload. Moreover select Manual sign in from organizer while uploading build.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Once check this.

Open your .plist file and check for "Bundle OS Type code" key. If that is not there, add a row and give that key and check the type it should be a string. And give "APPL" as value.

Clean the project and go for Archive.

I hope it will work for you.

Comment: This is the one correct my error. Also please see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57304115/3164091

Answer (score 3):

I've changed the Version number but forgot to change the Build version. Changing the Build version resolved the issue. Such a silly mistake. Smh...

Answer (score 3):

Make sure this is included in your Info.plist:

```
<key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
<string>APPL</string>
```

I had APPL misspelled as AAPL. Once I fixed that and signed into Application Loader and Xcode with the same Apple ID, everything worked.

Answer (score 3):

Since this is question obviously has different potential answers depending on the individual circumstances I thought I'd add my problem and what solved it:

**Problem:** I had someone copy the binary archive, make some changes and then pass the binary onto me. This caused a binary conflict.

**Solution:** I had to create a new certificate. I copied the bundle ID from the develop consul, pasted into xcode and was able to upload.

**Side note:** You can regenerate a new bundle id by turning on "In-App Purchases" under *Capabilities*.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

After few days I realize that, I've set Bundle ID wrong.

Here is how I correct,

Go **App Store Connect > Your App > App Information > General Information**

Select the Bundle ID you create and assign at xcode before.

Now you can Upload without error.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, check that you're using **the same accounts** in both Application Loaded (or XCode) and iTunes connect. Secondly, check that Bundle Id in error message and in iTunes connect are match, including **tHe cAsE**!

Comment: wrong logged account in ApplicationLoader was my problem! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you follow these steps in order:

1. Generate the App ID at https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/identifier/bundle
2. Generate your app from iTunes Connect selecting the Bundle ID created in step one
3. Upload the IPA from Application Loader or XCode

Comment: Please help! I'm stucked at Step 2 trying to "generate your app from iTunes Connect". For Step 1 I've already created the bundle, but in my iTunes Connect I don't see the app showing?

Comment: Exactly the issue is #2 , i'm stuck it's been like 4 hours already and it's not showing up under the drop down

Answer (score 2):

if your bundle id carried a capital letter and you've changed it to a lower case letter, you must run the application in the simulator before attempting to archive and upload to app store connect (this was the issue and solution for me).

Answer (score 2):

For me, what fixed it was to enter the required details in App Store Connect -> TestFlight -> Test Information.

Once I'd done that it seemed that Xcode realised there was a new app to allow uploading to and succeeded.

(Also check your caps in your Bundle ID though. )

Answer (score 2):

**iMessage Extension**: For everyone that is fighting with this problem with an messages extension (or any other extension) make sure you enter in "App Store Connect" -> "General Information" -> the Bundle-ID of the application target and not the extension target. We fought 2 days to find this out.

Answer (score 2):

For me : Just tried uploading using Application Loader and it worked

Answer (score 2):

If after you confirm your Bundle ID's match across App Store Connect, Apple Developer Portal, and Xcode and you are still having issues try this:

Remove the Apple ID associated with the Bundle ID you're experiencing issues with from your Accounts list in Xcode (Menu Bar -> Xcode -> Preferences -> Accounts). Then, add the Apple ID back to the Accounts list in Xcode.

Answer (score 2):

For me, it was because I forgot to create a "Provisioning Profile" on Apple developer portal. [I created a profile here](https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/profiles/list) for "App Store", then downloaded and opened the file and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

In my case I got it worked with opening the Application Loader inside the XCode.

Steps : XCode -> Open Developer tool -> Application Loader

When I opened it with Launchpad it failed to identify the correct account for the app. Therefore, it asked me to create an account.

With XCode , Application Loader could list down the accounts I'm entitled for. You have to select the correct account from the drop down.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the app was already set up, but the app version was already in use (waiting for review), I just needed to increase the version number.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was that my application had literally no information filled in the App Store Connect

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was using a different account, I created an app on Itunes but selected different account on Xcode. So just Selected the right account on Xcode and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

In my case

- Checked if same user in itunes and xcode
- Checked bundle ID is same

**Solution:**

Go to itunes inside the page of my app and inside the first tab "App Information" under the right hand side has a section "Others Information" click on the "edit user permission" and grant xcode user the permission to read the information of the app.

DONE

Answer (score 1):

When changed a project name from `HelloCordova` to that one I wanted I encouraged this problem. Even though in `PROJECT_NAME` -> `General` -> `Bundle Identifier` as well as in `PROJECT_NAME` -> `Build Settings` -> `Product Bundle Identifier` I changed it as it should be still had the same error. What solved the problem was simply to open a different editor and look for this string `PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER` and changed all the names I don't want to the correct ones. Apparently Xcode takes the bundle identifier also from somewhere else than these 2 locations.

Answer (score 1):

I got the error when uploading a React Native Expo bundle to Apple App Store Connect using Transporter. The problem was that I had transferred the app from my personal account to our company account but forgot to sign into our company account in Transporter.

Click the profile icon in the top right corner and sign in to the correct account that you are using in your bundle.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Had this happen to me and my case was an odd one.

I had multiple accounts added in Xcode, but only when i added my private account to the job-team in addition to the job-account, i encountered problems.

Turns out that xcode somehow checked for permissions with my private accounts who only had a customer-support role and not a developer role. It completely ignored my work-account that had the developer role.

Solution was to remove the account which lacked permissions, so that xcode used the proper account.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of frustration I came across this article....

[Does bundle id need to be case sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7688379/does-bundle-id-need-to-be-case-sensitive)

Hope this helps someone having the same issue as me.

Answer (score 0):

if your app transfer other account. You should rearrange Signing section for the corrcet team(new team)

Answer (score 0):

1. First login your developer account.
2. Check your bundle identiifer correctly
3. Then Check in your app store connect the new app is create or not as the same bundle identifier (is the main error)
4. Choose your correct bundle identifier to create new app.
5. Now you upload your app it get success.

Answer (score 0):

If you tried all the above and it did not work for you simply ensure the Identifier name matches with that of your app name.

Example: Let's say my identifier name is VictorDominic and my identifier is com.company.victordominic your app name should be VictorDominic if not you will get the above error.

Please take note of the casing. If your identifier name is Victordominic and your app name is VictorDominic you will still get this error.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I did all this but doesn't solve the problem so all I had to do is to assign the right bundle on the apple store connect ( the bundle id that is already exist in the IPA file )
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Check Requires full screen is enabled or not. If not enable it.

You can find that option in the below steps.

Targets -> General -> Deployment Info -> Requires full screen.