# Xcode Validation Error: No suitable records were found verify your bundle identifier is correct

Tags: ios, xcode6, app-store-connect

I have tried all the solutions from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29741404/no-suitable-records-were-found-verify-your-bundle-identifier-is-correct/29752513#29752513?newreg=78a15178f6074287be889db16feb3f3c) but they don't solve my problem.

The status of my app on itunes connect currently says "1.0 Prepare for Submission". I can't seem to find the section to change it to "Ready for upload" etc.

Please see screenshots:
[Screenshots](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/o0mkj0rc5s6p89j/AABFGqHl0RzhFpzTwvxgMelUa?dl=0)

Am I missing something here? Please enlighten me...

Comment: Your bundle identifiers are not same!

Comment: Omg I am so stupid. Thanks Jason!