# Issues with uploading from Xcode 9 to app store/ iTunes connect

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, app-store, app-store-connect

Hey I don't have much to say but I've been trying to upload my app to the App Store/ iTunes connect from Xcode 9 but whenever I do I get the same error message but I'm not 100% sure on how to fix the issue. If it helps I'm using Swift, Xcode, Cocoapods, and Firebase.

**Below is the Error Message**

No suitable application records were found. Verify your bundle identifier 'org.cocoapods.Protobuf' is correct.

Thanks

Comment: try solutions provided here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29741404/no-suitable-records-were-found-verify-your-bundle-identifier-is-correct

Comment: have you added app in itunes connect with bundle identifier 'org.cocoapods.Protobuf'

Comment: could the fact that it uses pods be the issue??????

Comment: @Brandon did u get the solution for this issue ?

Comment: Found solution?

Comment: I'm seeing this same issue, couldn't upload a build.

Comment: I tried to remove the Firebase pods. Now it's saying another pod bundle identifier is wrong. I guess this is related to other hidden problem instead of a specific pod.

Comment: @ShebinKoshy, @ishhhh: please check my answer. This is not a pod issue, instead, it's the `info.plist` key issue.

Answer (score 2):

By removing all of the pods, I figured out this is not related to the pods at all.

The error now became to "Could not find the main bundle or the Info.plist is missing a CFBundleIndentifier in ..."

After several hours debugging, I found in the `Info.plist`, there's a key named "Bundle OS Type code", my original value was `$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_PACKAGE_TYPE)`, this resulted into the error above.

By changing the value of `Bundle OS Type code` to `APPL`. I'm able to upload the app binary.

Comment: In my case in flutter ios project, everything was correct. But error message with "Asset validation failed" of different bundle id from third party library. 
This solved my problem. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was a problem with app access on appstoreconnect. In App information section, additional information subsection, edit user access option, you can change user access to the app.

We had a developer account configured along with the admin account in xcode. It seems xcode can't access app metadata when a developer account is active.

Either change app access to unlimited or log as admin on xcode. Hope this helps.