# No suitable application records were found. Verify your bundle identifier 'XXX.watchkitapp' is correct?

Tags: app-store-connect, watchkit, xcode9

I have been trying to upload an app with a corresponding watch kit app for the last 4 hours (not even an exaggeration) and I am at my wits end... I have deduced that there is something not recognising the bundle ID in iTunes connect but I have been unsuccessful in figuring out what it is or how to fix it and as consequence unsuccessful in uploading the app, This is the first time uploading this app from my current computer, as I recently upgraded. However in the passed I have uploaded successfully from my previous machine. I cannot validate the application either it just gives me the error  'No suitable application records were found. `Verify your bundle identifier 'XXXXXX.watchkitapp' is correct.` I have tried with application loader, same error. I hope someone can help me, as I said I am no closer to figuring it out than I was 4 hours ago.

Edit***
I have looked at this link [stack overflow question: no suitable records were found verify your bundle indentifier is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29741404/no-suitable-records-were-found-verify-your-bundle-identifier-is-correct) but it hasn’t helped, my issue is not with the ios app but the Apple Watch counterpart, I do not know where to find the applewatch expected bundle id in itunes connect further more I don’t believe either bundle IDs in Apple watch, watch app or watch kit extension is incorrect.

Edited (again)****
So I decided that if the appwatch app has been causing so much trouble as I have been trying to figure it out for 3 days now, why not just remove it for the time being.... so I did then I got a new error `No suitable application records were found. Verify your bundle identifier 'org.cocoapods.GTMSessionFetcher' is correct.` I tried everything that I tried on the previous issue to no avail. HELP PLEASE? This is really frustrating, maybe there is some file that didn't copy over with the project that controls the various bundle id's I don't know, really any help would be greatly appreciated I guess at present I'm just one step away from completely remaking the app in a new Xcode project....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No suitable records were found verify your bundle identifier is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29741404/no-suitable-records-were-found-verify-your-bundle-identifier-is-correct)

Comment: Could you please elaborate were might the duplicates be?

Comment: Any luck? I am having the same problem/ I've been uploading fine, until my latest build. Now its telling me my bundle code is incorrect, but it is not.

Comment: @Lee I'm banging my head for hours. I think this is related to apple.

Comment: @CihadTurhan - The only thing i can think, is that it has something to do with integrating Pods..- I've the correct certs, bundle ids etc.

Comment: @Lee I found the solution. See https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/72023#324473

Answer (score 0):

With a different Mac you probably need to download your certificates again. Also make sure you registered the bundle id in developer.apple.com

Comment: I do have the correct certificates on my Mac and the bundle id is registered at developer.apple.com, Thanks anyway, but unfortunately that hasn't helped.